# Map sql's BUILTIN\Administrators to Windows Administrators Group

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, permissions

Logged on as 'Administrator' (and a member of just one Group - Administrators) i am seen as God (ok ... god) to the SQL install.

Where do I bestow the same level of permission to all members of the Administrators group?

EDIT: The server's configured to accept Mix Login Mode in case that matters.

thx

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the server you want to manage. Expand Security, then Logins. Right-click on Logins and select New Login.

Next to the Login name box, click Search...

Change the Object Types to include Groups. If you're wanting to select Domain Admins (or similar), change the location to your domain, rather than the server.

Type the Administrators group name into the textbox and click OK.

On the left side, select the Server Roles page and check the `sysadmin` role. Finally, click OK.

Comment: Tried that and get: 
Create failed for Login 'machName\Administrators'.  - not found. I used the 'Advanced | Find' to be sure i didn't typo the spelling - and clicked 'Check Names'. Same non-joy. thx

Comment: Did you remember to change Object Types to include groups?

Comment: Right...that'd be the only way to see 'Administrators' and thus run the 'Check Names'.

Comment: I believe I know what's going on here. You just need to add BUILTIN\Administrators to the sysadmin role.  According to this KB article, that *is* the MACHINE\Administrators group. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216808/

Comment: If that doesn't get the job done, try mapping BUILTIN\Administrators do a login that is in db_owner on each database as well. You can do that under User Mapping in the login properties window.

Comment: Appreciate your sticking with this issue Ben. BUILTIN\Administrators already were mapped to sysadmin role. Toyed around with the 'per database mappings' as well with no success. I've come to the conclusion that i'm best off dealing with this on a User-by-User basis instead of Groups. ...again...appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, Steve. If it's not a large number of users, that probably won't be too bad, but it'll be a pain if it's a lot of people (or the group changes frequently). I hope your solution continues to work well for you.

Comment: Old question, but just wanted to add the 'not found' seems to come from UAC blocking use of the local administrators group.  Instead create a new local group, something like 'local db admins' and grant that access instead.  Just remember that group membership is calculated at login, so anyone already logged in needs to log off after being added to the group.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by creating a new local group called SQLUsers, I added the administrators group to the SQLUsers Group and was able to add this into the SQL server security > logins

Answer (score 0):

The workable alternative in my case turns out to be granting the permissions to each of the user accounts that need sql access.